# Rails scope test in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scope in worequests model:

```
scope :notcompl, where("statuscode_id != ?", Statuscode.last.id)
```

I would like to only show the edit button in the worequests show page if the worequest is notcompl.  I tried this and got undefined method:

```
<% if @worequest.notcompl? %>
  <= link_to 'Edit', edit_worequest_path(@worequest), :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

What is the correct syntax?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scope will find all the records that satisfy your condition.

It looks like what you want to do is check if the `worequest` has a `statuscode_id` of `Statuscode.last.id`. What you need is an instance method on your class instead of a scope:

```
 class Worequest < ActiveRecord::Base

    def not_complete?
        statuscode != Statuscode.last.id
    end
 end
```

Then in your view, you can check if the `Worequest` is complete or not:

```
<% if @worequest.not_complete? %>
  <= link_to 'Edit', edit_worequest_path(@worequest), :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

Also, defining a scope creates a method with the same name as the scope. So, calling `.notcompl` is not the same method as calling `.notcompl?` - which explains the undefined method issue you ran into.

Answer (score 0):

Scopes belong in models, not in controllers.  Move it to `Worequest` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope):

> Scope: Adds a **class method** for retrieving and querying objects.

The problem is that you are calling the `notcompl` method in an instance not in the class. `Worequest.notcompl` should work (not in the same example).

PS: See @alexBrand answer.